# CSS make divs appear to be "collected"

Tags: php, html, css

I have undefined (php determines how much) amount of divs appearing in another div. What i want is, the divs to appear that they are somehow collected. I don't know the right words to explain so i just made a little photomontage:

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

How can i achieve this effect. Do I need any other libraries or frameworks or something like that?

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Dryden: Ok i've successfully implemented it in the website ^.^ Works like a charm. Thank you! Please add this as an answer so i can accept. You were the first to comment/answer so i guess you deserve the credit :)

Comment: THis is a CSS solutuion to stack the blocks in columns vertically and evenly distributed: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mGJfK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want a 'masonry' style layout, checkout the isotope plugin by David DeSandro. Particularly the masonry layout style. http://isotope.metafizzy.co

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to use the `float` CSS property. So add to your `.post` CSS class the following:

```
float: left;
```

Comment: Works. Kind of. The divs now are just located on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
.post {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Remove center alignement otherwise the blocks are all centred.**

```
.siteContainer {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: vertical-align: top; Just aligns them. There is still this gap between the second and the first row.

Comment: The gap is caused by the tallest block in the row. This cannot be avoided in this case.